# Proof by contradiction for q $\Rightarrow (p \land $ $\neg p)$

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Hi everyone I'm doing an exercise of logic from the Science of programming book of David Gries, one of the exercises says:

> Prove that from $\neg q$ follows q $\Rightarrow (p   \land   $ $\neg p)$

I proved that in the following way:

From $\neg q$ infer $q \Rightarrow (p   \land   $ $\neg p)$

1. $\neg q$  Preposition 1.
2. from q infer p.

   2.1.  q Preposition 1.

   2.2 From $\neg p$ infer q $\land$ $\neg q$

   2.2.1 q $\land$ $\neg$q ($\land$-I, 1, 2.1).

   2.3 p ($\neg$-E, 2.2)
3. from q infer $\neg$ p.

   3.1.  q Preposition 1.

   3.2 From p infer q $\land$ $\neg q$

   3.2.1 q $\land$ $\neg$q ($\land$-I 1, 3.1).

   3.3 $\neg$p ($\neg$-I, 3.2)
4. p $\land$ $\neg$p ($\land$-I,2,3).
5. q $\Rightarrow (p   \land   $ $\neg p)$.  ($\Rightarrow$-I, 2, 4).

From my understading ths proof indicates that if q is false then q $\Rightarrow (p   \land   $ $\neg p)$ is true.

The doubt I have is with this proof:

> Prove that from q follows q $\Rightarrow (p   \land   $ $\neg p)$

that I proved in this way:

From q infer $q \Rightarrow (p   \land   $ $\neg p)$

1. q Preposition 1.
2. from $\neg q$  infer p.

   2.1.  $\neg q$  Preposition 1.

   2.2 From $\neg p$ infer q $\land$ $\neg q$

   2.2.1 q $\land$ $\neg$q ($\land$-I, 1, 2.1).

   2.3 p ($\neg$-I, 2.2)
3. from $\neg q$  infer $\neg$ p.

   3.1.  $\neg q$  Preposition 1.

   3.2 From p infer q $\land$ $\neg q$

   3.2.1 q $\land$ $\neg$q ($\land$-I 1, 3.1).

   3.3 $\neg$p ($\neg$-I, 3.2)
4. p $\land$ $\neg$p ($\land$-I,2,3).
5. q $\Rightarrow (p   \land   $ $\neg p)$.  ($\Rightarrow$-I, 1, 2, 4).

I'm not sure if that last proof is correct, because for q $\Rightarrow (p   \land   $ $\neg p)$ to be true  q has to be true and p $\land$ $\neg$ p has to be true, but  p $\land$ $\neg$ p is a contradiction, this never can be true, however my proof indicates that q $\Rightarrow (p   \land   $ $\neg p)$ can be infered from q, what I'm doing wrong?

These are the inference rules I'm using:

[image]

And this is the deductive system I'm using:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your first proof is fine; see (3.3.13) page 41:

> From $p, \lnot p$ infer $q$.

Thus, strating with premises $\lnot q$ and $q$ we have a 1st sub-proof: From $\lnot q, q$ infer $p$.

In the same way, we have a 2nd sub-proof: From $\lnot q, q$ infer $\lnot p$.

From them $(p \land \lnot p)$ follows using $(\land \text {-I})$ and we conclude with $q \to (p \land \lnot p)$ using $(\to \text {-I})$.

In conclusion we have:

> From premise $\lnot q$, the conclusion $q \to (p \land \lnot p)$ follows.

---

Regarding your second attempt, you have $q$ as premise and you have derived the contradiction $(p \land \lnot p)$ assuming also $\lnot q$.

Thus, when you conclude with $q \to (p \land \lnot p)$, there is still the premise $\lnot q$.

Obviously, we cannot prove $q \to (p \land \lnot p)$ because it is not a *tautology*.

Formula $(p \land \lnot p)$ **does not** follows from $\lnot q$ alone (neither from $q$ alone) [see [logical consequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_consequence#Proofs_and_models)] because   $(p \land \lnot p)$ is a *contradiction*, i.e. a formula that is always false, and there is an interpretation where $\lnot q$ is false but also an interpretation where $\lnot q$ is true.

Comment: Hi Mauro, thanks for your answer, I have a couple of questions:


1) Why my first proof can be proved? since we inferred it from premises that are a contradiction ¬,?

2) You mentioned the first proof is fine, what do you mean by fine? from what you said it seems like the conclusion for the first and second proof can't be proved, because they derive from a contradiction q,¬q. But I wonder why you wrote From premise ¬, the conclusion →(∧¬) follows.

Comment: Hi Mauro, sorry I edited my questions.

Comment: @oscar-net - the proof is fine means that you have correctly derived the resulkt according to the rules of your system. The rsult is obvous, because we have to prove that from $(q \land \lnot q)$ the conclusion $(p \land \lnot p)$ follows.

Comment: In my second attempt, we can't prove  →(∧¬) because that conclusion derives from ¬ as you pointed out, right? but we can prove ¬→(∧¬) because when  is false  ¬→(∧¬) is true.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151477/discussion-between-oscar-net-and-mauro-allegranza).

Comment: You have: 1) from $\lnot q$ it follows $q \to (p \land \lnot p)$ and 2)  from $q$ it follows $\lnot q \to (p \land \lnot p)$. The two are both logically correct and very similar. But you cannot prove neither $q \to (p \land \lnot p)$ nor $\lnot q \to (p \land \lnot p)$ because they are NOT tautologies (check it with truth table).

Comment: So what do you mean that we can write proofs that are fine, but there are some that can't be proved, like the ones I wrote? And for sure, it makes sense that they can't be proved because their premises are contradictions. Is that correct?

Comment: @oscar-net NO. From contradictory premises everything can be proved (see above). Maybe you have to review the basic concepts: tautology (page 14), theorem (page 26), deductive proof: From (premises), infer (conclusion) (page 41). Unfortunately, the book lacks of some basic notions, like that of *logical consequence* and that of *completeness* of a proof system

Comment: Having said that, the key point here is that some formula are *theorems* like $p \to (q \to p)$, while others are not, like $(q \to p)$. BUT some non-theorems can be derived from premises, in the form: From $p$,  infer $(q \to p)$.